# how register an interface that has no implentation with autofac?

Tags: autofac

How you I register an interface that has no implentation using Autofac?

I want Autofac to use DynamicProxy to generate interface your me!

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(IUserDao))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(SqlMapperInterceptor));


public class SqlMapperInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //todo: mapper sql file and return data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no mechanism to achieve this through the DynamicProxy2 integration provided by Autofac, but it can still be done by registering the generated proxy interface with Autofac directly:

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var proxyGen = new ProxyGenerator();
    return proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IUserDao>(new SqlMapperInterceptor());
})
.As<IUserDao>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something to intercept, otherwise it isn't interception. The solution is to create a dummy IUserDao implementation a.k.a. Null Object Pattern. This dummy cwn be registered as implementation in Autofac.

Comment: Hava any other way?i don't want to impl a null object class, i can use CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget by Castle.DynamicProxy，but i don't know how to do it with Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy。
`ProxyGenerator proxyGen = new ProxyGenerator();
var userDaoProxy = proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IUserDao>(new SqlMapperInterceptor());`